# Can't find Pycharm Duplicates tool window

Tags: pycharm

I'm trying to find the Duplicates Tool Window in Pycharm. I have Pycharm 2016.2.3. Is this something I need to install separately? The Pycharm documentation goes on about the tool window as thought it's already there, but nothing about what to do if it's not. [image: Image of my Tools menu here]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the tool in the wrong place. You can activate it by selecting Code -> Locate Duplicates on the main menu.